# Selectivity calculation of a Triple Pattern in Jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena

Does Jena have a class which has pre-computed statistics? For example this [paper](http://wwwconference.org/www2008/papers/pdf/p595-stocker1.pdf) talks about triple pattern selectivity. I know [this](http://rdfstats.sourceforge.net/) gives the histogram class, but I haven't been able to get it to work and the project doesn't seem to be supported anymore. The reason I ask is that, while I think calculating the selectivity of a subject and predicate seems pretty straightforward, I am not sure if I follow the selectivity of an object. The selectivity of an object is given by :

[image: selectivity of]

For some reason I am not sure how one calculates this histogram class for a bound and unbound object in jena? Does one calculate the number of instances in which the predicate and object appear for each class? and then divide it by the number of triples or is there something else to be done for this calculation?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I would be very interested in your solution